# code to find time until next business opening hour

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am currently using momentjs in my typescript/node code where, given a current time given by `const currentTime = moment()`, I wish to find the time until the next business opening hour. The business opening hours I have are 9am-5pm on Monday - Friday. Thus if the current time is Monday 7pm the time until the next business opening hour is in 14 hours (time until Tuesday 9am), and if it's Saturday 9pm, then the time until the next business opening hour is 36 hours (time until Monday 9am). This can obviously be solved by raw programming with many if statements, but I feel this should be enough of a common use case that there is already a library/package for this, or at the very least some kind of function already in momentjs. However, I have not been able to find anything remotely resembling my use case. Does anyone know if there is a simpler solution for my problem?

For context the following is my code to calculate the time until the next day:

```
const currentTime = moment();
const opening = moment('9:00am', 'h:mma');
const midnight = moment('12:00am', 'h:mma');
const nineAMNextDay = opening.add(1, 'day');
let timeUntilBusinessHours;
if (currentTime.day() === 1 || currentTime.day() === 2 || currentTime.day() === 3 || currentTime.day() === 4) {
      if (currentTime.isAfter(opening)) {
        timeUntilBusinessHours = nineAMNextDay.diff(currentTime, 'seconds');
      } else {
        timeUntilBusinessHours = opening.diff(currentTime, 'seconds');
      }
    } else if (currentTime.day() === 5) {
      if (currentTime.isBefore(opening)) {
        timeUntilBusinessHours = opening.diff(currentTime, 'seconds');
      } else {
        timeUntilBusinessHours = midnight.diff(currentTime, 'seconds') + 205200;
      }
    } else if (currentTime.day() === 6) {
      timeUntilBusinessHours = midnight.diff(currentTime, 'seconds') + 118800;
    } else if (currentTime.day() === 0) {
      timeUntilBusinessHours = midnight.diff(currentTime, 'seconds') + 32400;
    }
```

Comment: "Don't use moment js"? https://momentjs.com/docs/ the devs make a few recommendations for alternatives, which may work better for you.

Comment: "*I feel this should be enough of a common use case that there is already a library/package for this*". If you dig a little deeper, you'll see that you're asking a much more complex question than you think. Robust code to solve this should have standard business hours defined, plus weekends and holidays and any non–standard days, plus functions to find out whether the business is open or closed, plus the next open day and time, then finally the time until the next open time.